# Build bootstrap 3 on osx

Tags: npm, gruntjs

Im trying to build bootstrap 3 on osx. I have install npm using

```
brew install npm
```

then run

```
npm install
```

in the bootstrap directory. I would expect to be able to execute grunt now to build bootstrap, but there is no grunt on the PATH.

Im not very familiar with npm, so not sure what has gone wrong. Any help appreciated!

Thanks,
NFV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must run also `npm install -g grunt-cli`, which will install grunt globally in your system and make the `grunt` CLI tool available.

After you've done this, run `grunt` inside the project root directory.